# Creating an iOS Simulator Build with Cordova for Facebook review

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, cordova, review

I need to hand in a new version of our app to submit my request for new Facebook permissions.

The problem is, that it is not possible to build the iOS simulator build like described [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/creating-ios-simulator-build-for-review/).

I attached my complete output [on gist](https://gist.github.com/e3a03eb8c2de17dc774b.git).

The most important parts are these ones:

```
SebastiansMBP2:ios <user>$ xcodebuild -arch i386 -sdk iphonesimulator8.0
Build settings from command line:
    ARCHS = i386
    SDKROOT = iphonesimulator8.0

=== BUILD TARGET CordovaLib OF PROJECT CordovaLib WITH THE DEFAULT CONFIGURATION (Release) ===

Check dependencies
...
2014-10-21 11:44:28.029 xcodebuild[67280:364513]  DeveloperPortal: Using pre-existing current store at URL (file:///Users/<user>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DeveloperPortal%206.0.db).
=== BUILD TARGET <ProjectName> OF PROJECT <ProjectName> WITH THE DEFAULT CONFIGURATION (Release) ===


CompileC build/<ProjectName>.build/Release-iphonesimulator/<ProjectName>.build/Objects-normal/i386/AdjustCordova.o <ProjectName>/Plugins/com.adjust.sdk/AdjustCordova.m normal i386 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    cd /Users/<user>/Development/20/<ProjectName>/platforms/ios
    export LANG=en_US.US-ASCII
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/Users/<user>/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/bin:/Users/<user>/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@global/bin:/Users/<user>/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Users/<user>/.rvm/bin:/Users/<user>/.adt/tools:/Users/<user>/.adt/platform-tools"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c -arch i386 -fmessage-length=270 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -fcolor-diagnostics -std=c99 -fobjc-arc -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -Os -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Wno-receiver-is-weak -Wno-arc-repeated-use-of-weak -Wduplicate-method-match -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wuninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wbool-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wno-shorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wundeclared-selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.0.sdk -fexceptions -fasm-blocks -fstrict-aliasing -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -g -fvisibility=hidden -Wno-sign-conversion -fobjc-abi-version=2 -fobjc-legacy-dispatch -mios-simulator-version-min=7.0 -iquote /Users/<user>/Development/20/<ProjectName>/platforms/ios/build/<ProjectName>.build/Release-iphonesimulator/<ProjectName>.build/<ProjectName>-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/<user>/Development/20/<ProjectName>/platforms/ios/build/<ProjectName>.build/Release-iphonesimulator/<ProjectName>.build/<ProjectName>-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/<user>/Development/20/<ProjectName>/platforms/ios/build/<ProjectName>.build/Release-iphonesimulator/<ProjectName>.build/<ProjectName>-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /Users/<user>/Development/20/<ProjectName>/platforms/ios/build/<ProjectName>.build/Release-iphonesimulator/<ProjectName>.build/<ProjectName>-project-headers.hmap -I/Users/<user>/Development/20/<ProjectName>/platforms/ios/build/Release-iphonesimulator/include -I/Users/<user>/Development/20/<ProjectName>/platforms/ios/build/Release-iphonesimulator/usr/local/lib/include -I/Users/<user>/Development/20/<ProjectName>/platforms/ios/build/UninstalledProducts/include -I/Users/<user>/Development/20/<ProjectName>/platforms/ios/build/Release-iphonesimulator -I/Users/<user>/Development/20/<ProjectName>/platforms/ios/build/<ProjectName>.build/Release-iphonesimulator/<ProjectName>.build/DerivedSources/i386 -I/Users/<user>/Development/20/<ProjectName>/platforms/ios/build/<ProjectName>.build/Release-iphonesimulator/<ProjectName>.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/<user>/Development/20/<ProjectName>/platforms/ios/build/Release-iphonesimulator -F/Users/<user>/Development/20/<ProjectName>/platforms/ios/Safe -F/Users/<user>/Development/20/<ProjectName>/platforms/ios/<ProjectName>/Plugins/com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect -include /var/folders/pn/gg2pmp494ddc28vb35296c7r0000gn/C/com.apple.DeveloperTools/6.0-6A313/Xcode/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/<ProjectName>-Prefix-buzdrrssmquhyjccbctulbjeosdy/<ProjectName>-Prefix.pch -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/<user>/Development/20/<ProjectName>/platforms/ios/build/<ProjectName>.build/Release-iphonesimulator/<ProjectName>.build/Objects-normal/i386/AdjustCordova.d --serialize-diagnostics /Users/<user>/Development/20/<ProjectName>/platforms/ios/build/<ProjectName>.build/Release-iphonesimulator/<ProjectName>.build/Objects-normal/i386/AdjustCordova.dia -c /Users/<user>/Development/20/<ProjectName>/platforms/ios/<ProjectName>/Plugins/com.adjust.sdk/AdjustCordova.m -o /Users/<user>/Development/20/<ProjectName>/platforms/ios/build/<ProjectName>.build/Release-iphonesimulator/<ProjectName>.build/Objects-normal/i386/AdjustCordova.o
In file included from /Users/<user>/Development/20/<ProjectName>/platforms/ios/<ProjectName>/Plugins/com.adjust.sdk/AdjustCordova.m:9:
/Users/<user>/Development/20/<ProjectName>/platforms/ios/<ProjectName>/Plugins/com.adjust.sdk/AdjustCordova.h:9:9: fatal error: 'Cordova/CDV.h' file not found
#import <Cordova/CDV.h>
        ^
1 error generated.

... //////////  This error happens multiple times.

/Users/<user>/Development/20/<ProjectName>/platforms/ios/<ProjectName>/Plugins/com.aquto.cordova.AppleAdvertising/AppleAdvertising.h:2:9: fatal error: 'Cordova/CDV.h' file not found
#import <Cordova/CDV.h>
        ^
1 error generated.

** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    CompileC build/<ProjectName>.build/Release-iphonesimulator/<ProjectName>.build/Objects-normal/i386/AdjustCordova.o <ProjectName>/Plugins/com.adjust.sdk/AdjustCordova.m normal i386 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    CompileC build/<ProjectName>.build/Release-iphonesimulator/<ProjectName>.build/Objects-normal/i386/APPLocalNotification.o <ProjectName>/Plugins/de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification/APPLocalNotification.m normal i386 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    CompileC build/<ProjectName>.build/Release-iphonesimulator/<ProjectName>.build/Objects-normal/i386/CDVConnection.o <ProjectName>/Plugins/org.apache.cordova.network-information/CDVConnection.m normal i386 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    CompileC build/<ProjectName>.build/Release-iphonesimulator/<ProjectName>.build/Objects-normal/i386/CDVAssetLibraryFilesystem.o <ProjectName>/Plugins/org.apache.cordova.file/CDVAssetLibraryFilesystem.m normal i386 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    CompileC build/<ProjectName>.build/Release-iphonesimulator/<ProjectName>.build/Objects-normal/i386/AppDelegate.o <ProjectName>/Classes/AppDelegate.m normal i386 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    CompileC build/<ProjectName>.build/Release-iphonesimulator/<ProjectName>.build/Objects-normal/i386/CDVLocalFilesystem.o <ProjectName>/Plugins/org.apache.cordova.file/CDVLocalFilesystem.m normal i386 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    CompileC build/<ProjectName>.build/Release-iphonesimulator/<ProjectName>.build/Objects-normal/i386/CDVDevice.o <ProjectName>/Plugins/org.apache.cordova.device/CDVDevice.m normal i386 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    CompileC build/<ProjectName>.build/Release-iphonesimulator/<ProjectName>.build/Objects-normal/i386/AppleAdvertising.o <ProjectName>/Plugins/com.aquto.cordova.AppleAdvertising/AppleAdvertising.m normal i386 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(8 failures)
```

No I run the command with the workspace set up and the scheme as well.

```
SebastiansMBP2:ios <user>$ xcodebuild -arch i386 -sdk iphonesimulator8.0 -workspace <ProjectName>.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace -scheme <ProjectName>
Build settings from command line:
    ARCHS = i386
    SDKROOT = iphonesimulator8.0

=== BUILD TARGET CordovaLib OF PROJECT CordovaLib WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===

Check dependencies

2014-10-21 11:44:44.905 xcodebuild[67925:365372]  DeveloperPortal: Using pre-existing current store at URL (file:///Users/<user>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DeveloperPortal%206.0.db).
=== BUILD TARGET <ProjectName> OF PROJECT <ProjectName> WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===

Check dependencies

....

** BUILD SUCCEEDED **
```

Now I run the generated build on an `ios-sim`:

```
SebastiansMBP2:ios <user>$ ios-sim launch /Users/<user>/Development/20/<ProjectName>/platforms/ios/build/Release-iphonesimulator/<ProjectName>.app
Session could not be started: Error Domain=LaunchServicesError Code=0 "Unable to run app in Simulator" UserInfo=0x7f8993721ad0 {Error=ExecutableTwiddleFailed, ErrorDescription=Failed to chmod file:///Users/<user>/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B745FCEF-0713-419B-B5EF-5274C912DA7E/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.containermanagerd/Temp/Bundle/Application/D615484C-04F7-496D-AB61-4A988E4357C3/<ProjectName>.app/<ProjectName> : No such file or directory, NSLocalizedFailureReason=An error was encountered while running (Domain = LaunchServicesError, Code = 0), NSUnderlyingError=0x7f8993415850 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (LaunchServicesError error 0.)", NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to run app in Simulator}
```

(username, project name and other privacy related parts have been replaced)

Do you have any ideas how to fix this and how to build a version that can be used to upload it to Facebook?

I'm running `Xcode 6`, updated the `ios-sim` to version `3.0.0` and updated `cordova-cli` to version `4.0.0` with the iOS platform version `3.6.3`.

Building the application via `cordova build iOS` and via `Xcode` directly works fine!

Thanks!

Comment: Also having this issue, exact same error and symptoms

Comment: Issue is now resolved - I carefully went through the build process and removed plugins etc, and then when I re-added them in the build script it worked. So unfortunately can't trace the issue of this, so the bounty is there in case someone is able to pinpoint the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just as an information for you guys, I was able to solve it by running the application from Xcode and then just zipping the content of the `iOS/build/Emulator/` folder. 
The biggest difference between both is, that the mentioned folder contains a separate library `libCordova.a` and a folder `include`. With this two elements I was able to hand the iOS application in to Facebook (I just added them to the ZIP-File).

Hope this helps you ;)

Comment: Could you explain a bit more, how you executed the .app file via xcode ??

Comment: Thank you!! Just click play button on Xcode and zip the `emulator` folder. That's it. run `ios-sim launch <yourapp>.app` if you'd like to test.

Comment: isn't that a debug build? they are asking for a release build

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and was related to the cordova-ios version. I had to upgrade it, and then it solved the issue. Cordova-ios with problem was 4.3.0